# Create variables with other variables in batch

Tags: batch-file, variables

I have a variable called v23. I tryed to verify if it is equal with 6 like this:

`set x=2
 set y=3
 if %v%x%%y%%==6 echo ok`

But it didn't work so i did this:

```
echo %v%x%%y%%
```

and it echoes:

> x%y%

How can I recreate the v23 variable with x and y? (an array wont work for my entire algorithm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's one of the FAQ, if not the most often asked question.
Use [delayed expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\05\20\SO_50438603.cmd
@Echo off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set x=2
set y=3
set v23=6
if !v%x%%y%!==6 echo v%x%%y% is !v%x%%y%!
```

Sample output:

```
> SO_50438603.cmd  
v23 is 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't been specific with the task, so I thought I'd provide an option which doesn't require delayed expansion:

```bat
Set "v23=6"

Set "x=2"
Set "y=3"

Set /A #=(x * y) - v23
If %#% Equ 0 Echo OK

Pause
```